# How to make a bat file to detect if something is written in a .txt document

Tags: batch-file, detection

How to make a bat file to detect if something is written in a .txt document and use that information

Like this:

`name.txt` contains: `Bob`

`saymyname.bat` outputs `Hello "Bob"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set /p name= <name.txt
echo Hello "%name%"
pause
```

This will put the first line of text in name.txt inside the variable name, and then echo that.

If you only want to output Hello Bob if %name% contains a variable you should do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "name="<name.txt
if not "!name!"=="" echo Hello "%name%"
pause
```

EDIT:

For multiple lines:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (name.txt) DO if not "%%G"=="" echo Hello "%%G"
pause
```

Comment: But how to detect multiple lines in name.txt?Like the next line.

Comment: Edited for multiple lines

Comment: The brackets and quotes are for respectively empty variables and special signs

Comment: @Mofi It seems you're right. However, I filled a text-file with "
`!`
`%`
`~`
`^`
`&`
` `
`"""`
`"TXL42ETW5" is a 42" TV`
`2>nul`
`cmd.exe & echo Test`
`dir %windir% | more`
`%%`
`!!`
`^!`
`^%`
`>>`
`"&"^&`
`" == | more"`
`!variable02:~0,1!`
`"^^!variable02:~0,1^^!"`
`^'`
`"!"`
`"/?"`
`%ERRORLEVEL%`
`!ERRORLEVEL!` and none of these gave me an error, so brackets aren't necesary, but it doesn't break on uneven amounts of qoutes either.